# React components to render two kinds of form elements

Tags: form, template, react.js, jsx

I have two React components. The only difference is the input tag vs select tag. I'm trying to move the bulk of the duplicate code to a higher order component but I can't wrap my head around it. Any suggestions?

```
import React from "react";
import Style from "./style.scss";

export class FloatingLabelInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { label, ...props } = this.props;
        const clsOK = props.value ? Style.ok : "";
        return (
            <div className={`${Style.wrapper}`}>
                <input className={`${Style.input} ${clsOK}`} ref={el => this.input = el} {...props} />
                <label className={`${Style.label}`} htmlFor={props.id}>{label}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export class FloatingLabelDropDown extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { label, ...props } = this.props;
        const clsOK = props.value ? Style.ok : "";
        return (
            <div className={`${Style.wrapper}`}>
                <select
                    className={`${Style.input} ${clsOK}`}
                    ref={el => this.input = el} {...props} >
                    {this.props.children}
                </select>
                <label className={`${Style.label}`} htmlFor={props.id}>{label}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an understanding of what you are trying to do, but because `select` has children and and `input` does not it's a little tricky but this is what I came up with:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class FloatingLabel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <this.props.render option='Hello'  />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class SelectDropDown extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        <option>{this.props.option}</option>
      </select>
    )
  }
}

class InputDropDown extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input />
    )
  }
}


render(<FloatingLabel render={SelectDropDown} />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

In this example you can create a `<FloatingLabel />` component that can either take a `SelectDropDown` or a `InputDropDown` component as a prop. You can then render that prop in the `FloatingLabel` parent and pass whatever props that you need to pass down to the children.

Basically what you would be changing is the everything inside the `div` except for the label.

Comment: I think you've got me on the right path. The missing piece of the puzzle was passing the child component as a prop.